# Graham ANSI Common Lisp 6.6 Function builders: Recursive implementation of compose?

Tags: common-lisp

After some contemplation I understand how the compose function described in Graham's ANSI Common Lisp chapter 6.6 (p. 110) works:

```
(defun compose (&rest functions)
  (destructuring-bind (fn .  fns) (nreverse functions)
    #'(lambda (&rest arg)
    (reduce #'(lambda (x y) (funcall y x))
        fns
        :initial-value (apply fn arg)))))

(setf (symbol-function 'lst-gt10p)
      (compose #'list
           #'(lambda (x) (and (> x 10) t))))

(lst-gt10p 11)
```

But somehow I am unable to provide a recursive definition of compose.

E.g. here is an attempt of a recursive implementation:

```
(defun rec-compose (&rest functions)
  (destructuring-bind (fn . fns) functions
    #'(lambda (&rest args)
    (cond
      ((null fns) (apply fn args))
      (t (funcall fn
              (apply #'rec-compose fns)))))))

(funcall (rec-compose #'list #'round #'sqrt) 11)
```

The idea is to keep calling `(funcall fn (apply #'rec-compse fns))` until it hits the base case `(apply fn args)`. Yet this returns not the result but another closure..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined in the post, every time that `rec-compose` is called a function is created. Since `rec-compose` is recursively called, it attempts to create a function that returns a function which returns a function....

A solution is to create a helper function inside of the anonymous function returned by `rec-compose` which is itself recursively called so that the recursion does not keep piling up functions:

```
(defun rec-compose (&rest functions)
  #'(lambda (&rest args)
      (labels ((combine (functions)
                 (destructuring-bind (fn . fns) functions
                   (if (null fns)
                       (apply fn args)
                       (funcall fn (funcall #'combine fns))))))
        (combine functions))))
```

```
CL-USER> (funcall (rec-compose #'sqrt #'+) 9 16)
5.0
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it seems very obvious now. Apparently I am still having serious trouble with all that recursive stuff..